# Creating vector MbTile file from source of lat / long points?

Tags: postgresql, vector, mbtiles

I need to create a vector mbTile, not a raster one, to be compatible with the application that uses it.

I have a postgres database that has many rows, each one representing an item with a lat and long position. Of course I can export that to CSV if required.

What should I use to create the vector mbtile? I have tried with tilemill, but it creates a raster file.

Comment: You mention "to be compatible with the application that uses it", what application are you attempting to create a file for?  Have you tried using GDAL to convert rasters to mbtile?  https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2017/03/06/raster2mbtiles/

Comment: I haven't used gdal no, but it seems odd to go from csv > rasta > vector.

Comment: I'm supplying the vector mbtiles to a mobile developer for inclusion in his  ios app displaying the data offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use mapbox tippecanoe takes GEOJSON as input produces mbtiles or folder of PBF
It's a Linux application but runs great in bash for Windows 10
tippecanoe -z5 -o filtered.mbtiles name.geosjon
https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

t-rex https://github.com/t-rex-tileserver/t-rex has worked well producing vector tiles for me. There is a way to generate the tiles and looks like an mbtile option too http://t-rex.tileserver.ch/doc/generate/

This links well with postgres/postgis as you noted was your data source.